# Rewrite requests to different enpoint with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have site on joomla and subfolder **folder** with standalone php files.

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    backend;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 90;
    }
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
location ~ /forder/(.*)\.php {
     try_files $uri /folder/app.php?controller=$1;
}
```

When I go to https://site/folder/script.php nginx send source code of that file.
Where I go wrong?

Comment: What is the document root (value of the `root` directive) and where is the `script.php` file relative to that?

Comment: root - /var/www, file - /var/www/folder/script.php

Comment: Try: `location /folder/ { try_files $uri /folder/app.php?controller=$1; }`

Comment: Thank you but it is doesn't help. I've found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me is to put

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
 rewrite /folder/(.*)\.php /folder/app.php?controller=$1 last;
}
```

in `server` section